# Change permission recursively for all directory and exclude only one directory

Tags: recursion, chmod

I would like to change the permission recursively all files and directories but exclude some directories.

`find . -name user -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

But using this, its only change the directories but not recursively. The content of directories not change.

while,

`find . -name user -prune -o -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;`

This will change all directories and its contents and include the 'user'directory which i want to exclude.

So, how to change the permission recursively all files and directories but exclude user directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also *exclude* the specific user directory, while including everything else.

1. Switch the file search to **wholename** on all sub-things of **user**
2. On the "or directory", add an exclusion for **user**

I think this does it

```
find . -wholename "*user/*" -prune -o \
    -type d -a -wholename^"./user$" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
```